# Maven J2EE archetype in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Whenever I create a maven J2EE archetype in my eclipse IDE, I get the following weird project structure in my work-space where it treats each folder as it own independent folder.

[image]

Is the project structure suppose to turn out like that?

---

Inside the project folder, it looks more like how I expected it to look.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is normal and is the way that Eclipse copes with nested projects.

There was a time when it could not do this at all and you had to structure your project with the parent pom in a directory adjacent to the others especially for Eclipse.

You will occasionally encounter old projects structured like this for that very reason.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried J2EE archetype but consider J2EE is very old term (now J2EE term was replaced with Java EE, for your information J2EE was used until version 4 and Java EE start from version 5).

In J2EE is common practice to separate each project, you will have many `jar` for your EJB and `war` for your Web project and then you will need `EAR` to bundle all of your module project.

But now with Java EE you just need `war` for everything. It's more simple rather than using EAR. So, if you want to build Java EE project I suggest you to see this minimalist [Java EE maven archetype](https://github.com/AdamBien/javaee7-essentials-archetype)